# Cross out text when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome Extension that allows the user to create a todo list. So far I am able to type in a task and submit it.  The user is also able to check off the todo list.  Currently, I am trying to make it so if the user checks off a task, the text has a line through it.

**This is the Javascript code that I tried using:**

```
$(() => {
  $('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      const newTask = $(this).val();
      if (newTask) {

        var li = $("<li><input type='checkbox'><label>" + newTask + "</label></li>");
        $('#tasksUL').append(li);
        $(this).val("");
      }
    }
    if (document.getElementById("checkbox").checked)
    {
      document.getElementById("tasksUL").style.textDecoration="line-through"
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="newtask" value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New Task" id="newtask">
<ul id="tasksUL">
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="newtaskitem" style="margin-right: 30px"><label>test</label></li>
</ul>
```

**Original Javascript:**

```
$(() => {
  $('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      const newTask = $(this).val();
      if (newTask) {

        var li = $("<li><input type='checkbox'<label>" + newTask + "</label></li>");
        $('#tasksUL').append(li);
        $(this).val("");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a class with `text-decoration: line-through;`. On clicking on the checkbox you can simply toggle the class using [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

**Please Note:** It is good practice to avoid inline CSS. I have added another class to set margin property.

```js
$(() => {
  $('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      const newTask = $(this).val();
      if (newTask) {
        var li = $("<li><input type='checkbox' class='right-margin' <label>" + newTask + "</label></li>");
        $('#tasksUL').append(li);
        $(this).val("");
      }
    }
  });
  
  $('body').on('click', ':checkbox', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('stroked');
  });
});
```

```css
.stroked { 
  text-decoration: line-through; 
}
.right-margin{
  margin-right: 30px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="newtask" value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New Task" id="newtask">
<ul id="tasksUL">
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="newtaskitem" class="right-margin"><label>test</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

I rather use just a css `pseudo-class` easy and effective.

```css
#newtaskitem[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
  text-decoration: line-through; 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="newtask" value="test" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New Task" id="newtask">
<ul id="tasksUL">
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="text" id="newtaskitem" style="margin-right: 30px"><label>Welcome to Droplet's 'Tasks' feature!</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the below line

```
document.getElementById("checkbox").checked
```

You are calling a element by its tagname.

Analyzing your requirement I suggest you to bind a separate event to handle the checkbox

@mamun's answer is good to follow. For more fine tuning you can bind change event rather than click event.

Answer (score 0):

this works for any new list elements you add too

```js
$('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    const newTask = $(this).val();
    if (newTask) {

      var li = $("<li><input class='taskInput' style='margin-right: 30px' type='checkbox'><label>" + newTask + "</label></li>");
      $('#tasksUL').append(li);
      $(this).val("");
    }
  }
});

$(document).on('change', '.taskInput', function() {
  console.log('changed')
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).siblings().css('text-decoration', 'line-through')
  } else {
    $(this).siblings().css('text-decoration', 'none')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="newtask" value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New Task" id="newtask">
<ul id="tasksUL">
  <li class="taskLI"><input class="taskInput" type="checkbox" id="newtaskitem" style="margin-right: 30px"><label class="textLabel">Welcome to Droplet's 'Tasks' feature!</label></li>
</ul>
```